# KL divergence minimization

Tags: bayesian

I have seen different derivations of KL divergence problems. Up to here, I understand everything:

[image]

Then in next step we get:

[image]

See:

[image]

But this just can not be true:

[image]

I am sure I am missing something, but I just can not understand it what.

additional information:

I do not understand How Q(z) * log(P(x)) becomes log(P(x)). My question would be why Q(z) * log(P(z,x)/Q(z)) doesnt become just log(P(z,x)/Q(z)) if sum of Q(z) is always one as we know.

In lower part I have presented this with two sets of random variables for Q and P distribution. When applying Q(z) * log(P(x)) with these random variables, I get completely different result if there would be only log(P(x)).

q*x = x only if q = 1, but in my case as it is evident q*x is not x, therefore q is not one.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to derive, and it is not clear to me what your question is.  Can you provide a bit of context, please, and formulate a particular question, please?

Comment: @kimchilover I updated. Thank you.